# Have multiple ec2 instances execute remote script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know I can make a AMI of an instance and launch multiple identical servers, but if I need to make changes to a script I need to edit them one by one or make another AMI. Is there any way to have my ec2 instances use a script from a master instance or any other solution to this issue.

Comment: There are lots of potential solutions to this.  You can use a configuration management tool like Ansible, Puppet, Chef, etc. to ensure the script is always up-to-date on each host, you could have each host fetch the script from a central web server before executing it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The recently announced EC2 run command may be what you need:

> Run Command is a feature that enables you to securely manage the
>   configuration of your Amazon EC2 instances. Run Command provides a
>   simple way of automating common administrative tasks like executing
>   Shell scripts and commands on Linux, running PowerShell commands on
>   Windows, installing software or patches, and more. Run Command allows
>   you to execute these commands across multiple instances and provides
>   visibility into the results, making it easy to manage configuration
>   change across fleets of instances.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-run-command-remote-instance-management-at-scale/